# Convert std::basic_string to NSString in Objective-C / Cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, stdstring

How do I convert a std::basic_string to a NSString ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSString stringWithCString: myBasicString.c_str() encoding: NSWhateverStringEncoding];`

Comment: @Snej: What cases you can think of?

Comment: @KennyTM: more to the point, what cases does @Snej need covering?